# SQL query with requires recursive logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `MySQL` table and it has 2 columns which record users' login info:

```
 User_id  Device_id
     a       123
     b       123
     b       321
     d       321
     e       aaa
     f       ccc
     g       cba
     h       aaa
     h       ccc
     i       cba
     i       aaa
```

Now I want to add a column `Group`: if user_id are logined by the same group of device, then put them together. For instance, as shown below, user account `a` and `b` are logined on device `123`, so `a` and `b` are in the same group. While user account `b` is also logined on device `321`, then all accounts logined by `321` should join this group
:

```
 User_id  Device_id    Group 
     a       123         1
     b       123         1
     b       321         1
     d       321         1
     e       aaa         2
     f       ccc         2
     g       cba         2
     h       aaa         2
     h       ccc         2
     i       cba         2
     i       aaa         2
```

This cannot be simply dealed with `group by` so how to use SQL to express column `Group`?

Comment: Note that this problem requires recursive logic. What version of MySQL are using?

Comment: What is "group of device" ?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your reply. I am using `MySQL` 8.5

Comment: @Serg Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried to detail my description. Hope is helps..

Comment: Hi @Strawberry Actually I can migrate this `MySQL` table to `Hadoop` platform and deal it with `Hive` and query grammar there is much more flexible. So difference between `MySQL` versions is actually not a big deal. You can use the version you like most :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below queries,

// For future insert

INSERT INTO tableName
VALUES (j, '123', CASE grouping 
WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM tableName tn WHERE tn.Device_id='123')=0 THEN (SELECT MAX(tn.grouping)+1 FROM tableName tn)
WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM tableName tn WHERE tn.Device_id='123')>0 THEN (SELECT tn.grouping FROM tableName tn WHERE tn.Device_id='123')
END
);

//Update the existing data

UPDATE tableName
set grouping = CASE grouping 
WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM tableName tn WHERE tn.Device_id='123')=0 THEN (SELECT MAX(tn.grouping)+1 FROM tableName tn)
WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM tableName tn WHERE tn.Device_id='123')>0 THEN (SELECT tn.grouping FROM tableName tn WHERE tn.Device_id='123')
END;

Comment: Hello Devanathan M, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify how a MYSQL TRIGGER will help to solve the problem?

Comment: In MySQL, a trigger is a stored program invoked automatically in response to an event such as insert, update, or delete that occurs in the associated table. For example, you can define a trigger that is invoked automatically before a new row is inserted into a table. So as soon as you get an entry in the table you can update the Group column by referring to existing rows.

Comment: I know the concepts of a MySQL trigger. The point I was framing was your answer being broad. A better answer would be something like "Use a mysql trigger on this event and do that"